# Can I connect with SQL Plus to oracle database in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, sqlplus

Is it possible to connect to my database in oracle with SQL Plus in vb.net?
I need to receive some values in Chinese characters from Oracle 11g database.
If I select a row into SQL Developer, it doesn't work but when I select into SQL Plus my characters in Chinese are displayed correctly.

Comment: Have you considered managed oracle client instead?

Comment: SQL Plus is a GUI client for humans to use. Use the ADO.NET libraries for Oracle in your code. Probably there's some documentation and tutorials around if you search online.